# Adding a Cross Database Reference to a VS2012 Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have the following scenario:

**Context:**

I have created a new Database Project within a Solution in VS2012 connected to TFS. This Database Project has views, stored procs etc. in it. Specifically, one of the views refers to a database table on a different server (running SQL Server 2008R2). For various reasons, I don't want to import this database into the current solution as a separate database project or even as a stand alone Solution with just it as a Database Project.

**The Problem:**

If I try build this Database Project (before publishing it to a SQL instance) in VS2012 - it fails, quite clearly, with an unresolved reference. This is I believe because it can not 'see' the external server and database and table.

**The Question:**

How do you add a cross database reference inside a VS2012 Database Project which references a table/view on a different server and SQL instance?

I've scanned the internet for an answer and I've found a few resources which speak of SQLCLR values, data tier applications, aliases and the like but nothing quite what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I should mention too that I'm a novice at VS in general.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Data-Tier Application, or DACPAC, then add a database reference for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231291.aspx